# URLENCODE Variable in Salesforce Vertical Response Email

Tags: html, salesforce, urlencode, force.com

This is a rather simple question, but I cannot find documentation about it from Salesforce.

I am setting up an HTML Newsletter from Salesforce Vertical Response, and I need to put a link in the body of the email that goes to another site which takes the user's email address as a query string. I am doing this so that when the user clicks the link from the HTML email, they will automatically be signed up for a different blog mailing list.

The link will look like this `www.mywebsite.com/blog/subscribe?email=your_email@email.com`.
I can easily accomplish this by using the {EMAIL_ADDRESS} variable, such that the link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/subscribe?email={EMAIL_ADDRESS}">Subsribe</a>
```

This workds, but when the user gets the email and clicks the link, the '@' symbol gets stripped from the URL. Now I'm trying to figure out how to get around this. I saw some documentation on the URLENCODE() function for SalesForce, but when I try to use it in the HTML email editor in SalesForce, like `URLENCODE({EMAIL_ADDRESS})`it doesn't execute it, and instead interprets it literally as text. Can anyone help me? is it even possible to use functions from within the SalesForce HTML email editor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent used VerticalResponse, but if it leans on salesforce communication templates then you can always create an email template as Visualforce page. Then you can apply `Encode` functions to merge fields.

Comment: Thanks, I think that will work to use VisualForce templates in VerticalResponse, The docs list this as a feature: "Access your saved Salesforce Templates to use as VerticalResponse emails."

I'll give it a shot. In the meantime I found an easier workaround of using $_POST with a form rather than a hyperlink with $_GET so that I don't even have to worry about URL's anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you were able to find a workaround. If you ever go back to dealing with the URL, it's a good idea to disable our click-tracking when working with merge fields. This can be accomplished by adding nr_ before the http. Example: Subsribe - If you ever try that and it doesn't work, or if you have any other questions, please let us know via one of our Support channels:

support@verticalresponse.com
866-683-7842 x1
We also have live chat available: http://help.verticalresponse.com/

Regards,

Keith Gluck
VerticalResponse Customer Support